# Ubuntu 20.04 PC regularly accessing the RAID disk: could the barrier option be the problem?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have a new desktop PC on which I installed Ubuntu **20.04** (server edition). The two hard disks (not SSDs) are in a **RAID** formatted with **ext4**. The disks are regularly making noises like they are being accessed every few seconds.

Lots of old threads on this can be found, but I'm wondering if there is anything specific to Ubuntu 20.04 or RAIDs that might explain the constant disk accesses?

I've seen a case where the user said specifying the **barrier=0** mount option on the ext4 partitions solved the problem.

Setting a **commit=60** option was also suggested.

**Are these safe and reasonable changes to try?**

According to the mount command, my two ext4 partitions currently use these options:

```
/dev/md2p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/md0p1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

When I run 'sudo iotop -oa', **jbd2**/md2p1-8 is consistently at the top.

Prior to this new PC, I used Ubuntu 18 on a 2013 PC, also with a 2-disk RAID, and I did not have this problem.

mdadm says "active sync" for all partitions involved.

uname says: 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks.